# MySQL left join 3 tables error

Tags: mysql, join

I am having trouble joining mutiple tables.
I can get 2 to join, but I get an error when I try to join all three:

**This works:**

```
SELECT `capman`.`cman_code`, `capman`.`cman_name`, `caprange`.`cran_name`, `caprange`.`cran_mantextcode` 

from capman, caprange 

LEFT JOIN `capder` ON `caprange`.`cran_code` = `capder`.`cder_rancode` 

AND `capder`.`cder_discontinued` = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' 
LIMIT 10
```

**And this works:**

```
SELECT `capman`.`cman_code`, `capman`.`cman_name`, `caprange`.`cran_name`, `caprange`.`cran_mantextcode`

from capman

LEFT JOIN `caprange` ON `caprange`.`cran_mantextcode` = `capman`.`cman_code` WHERE LCASE(cman_name) IN ('arbarth','alfa romeo','aston')
LIMIT 10
```

**But when I try to put them together like this:**

```
SELECT `capman`.`cman_code`, `capman`.`cman_name`, `caprange`.`cran_name`, `caprange`.`cran_mantextcode`

from capman, caprange 

LEFT JOIN `caprange` ON `caprange`.`cran_mantextcode` = `capman`.`cman_code` WHERE LCASE(cman_name) IN ('arbarth','alfa romeo','aston')

LEFT JOIN `capder` ON `caprange`.`cran_code` = `capder`.`cder_rancode` AND `capder`.`cder_discontinued` = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'

LIMIT 10
```

**I get the error:**
*Not unique table/alias: 'caprange'*

Comment: just remove `caprange` here `from capman, caprange `

Comment: You're mixing join notation which usually throws an error.  I'm really surprised your first one worked!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you mean to join caprange twice. If so, you can use alias to point to the right table. The query could be rewritten as:

```
SELECT `capman`.`cman_code`, `capman`.`cman_name`, `caprange`.`cran_name`, `caprange`.`cran_mantextcode`
from capman, caprange r1 
LEFT JOIN `caprange` r2 ON r2.`cran_mantextcode` = `capman`.`cman_code` WHERE LCASE(cman_name) IN ('arbarth','alfa romeo','aston')
LEFT JOIN `capder` ON r1.`cran_code` = `capder`.`cder_rancode` AND `capder`.`cder_discontinued` = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
LIMIT 10
```

Since I am not sure which table you are joining with caprange, replace r1/r2 in the query with the right alias.